# Drupal redirect module not working with +

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect, drupal

I am using Drupal Redirect Module to redirect old urls to new Drupal URL.

However the URLs with + are not redirect, changing + to %2B the URls are working.

Can you please help me resolve this or 
a Simple mod-rewrite rule to change + to %2B on all the urls will aslo do

Comment: how does your current rule look?

Comment: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/